# Prime number theorem result for Hasse-Weil zeta functions

Tags: number-theory, reference-request, algebraic-number-theory

Let $L(E, s) = \sum_{n} a(E, n)/n^s$ be the Hasse-Weil zeta function for an elliptic curve E, $\psi_E(x)=\sum_n a(E, n)$.

I know that one can get an analogue to prime number theorem, namely $\psi_E(x) = cx+O(x^{1-\epsilon})$. Is there a writeup somewhere that I can read about this?

Comment: Note that for the standard prime number theorem, we don't know an error term as strong as $\psi(x)-x = O(x^{1-\varepsilon})$ (that would be a "pseudo-Riemann hypothesis", a groundbreaking result). So I'm doubtful we have such a good error term for $\psi_E$ either. Nevertheless, the techniques are the same as for the standard prime number theorem, once one establishes an analytic continuation/functional equation/zero-free region for $L(E,s)$.

Comment: @GregMartin Thanks. I take that with GRH the proof is identical to that of PNT assuming RH?

Comment: Hmmm ... then there's a dissonance between the words and the notation being used.